# Error: missing property on object 'AppDelegate *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Teaching myself iOS Programming, and starting by following [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028642.do).
I ran into error "Property 'MainViewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'.

I've double and triple checked that I followed the code correctly, even restarted from scratch. I've scoured StackOverflow and tried a few solutions but none worked and few properly match my issue. Any help?

AppDelegate.m (where the error lies)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WeatherForecast.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    WeatherForecast *forecast = [[WeatherForecast alloc] init];
    self.MainViewController.forecast = forecast;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "WeatherForecast.h"

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)showInfo;
- (IBAction)refreshView:(id) sender;
- (void)updateView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) WeatherForecast *forecast;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be in your second line of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. `self.MainViewController` is expecting a property in your AppDelegate. Just remove this line and add `controller.forecast = forecast;` before `return YES.` At this point you got a reference to your MainViewController and can set the property safely (assuming that MainViewController is set up as the current rootViewController through your Storyboard or XIB).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
   WeatherForecast *forecast = [[WeatherForecast alloc] init];
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
   controller.forecast = forecast;
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Although this assumes that the MainViewController is the rootViewController, I think it's a safe assumption here.

Comment: Meant to add this assumption as well, now I refined the answer accordingly.